# How do I 'donut cache' in ASP.NET MVC for something more than a date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, donut-caching

All the examples for donut caching I've seen are just like this :

```
 <%= Html.Substitute( c => DateTime.Now.ToString() )%>
```

Thats fine if I just want the date, but what other options are there?

I know there is a delegate 'MvcSubstitutionCallback' which has the following signature :

```
 public delegate string MvcSubstitutionCallback(HttpContextBase httpContext);
```

but `RenderAction` and `RenderPartial` returns void so i cant just return them from the delegate method. How can I effectively use this callback for more complex situations.

I've looked at both of Phil Haacked's articles [here](http://www.haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx) and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx), but neither seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Any update on this?  Do you have a html helper that works now?

Comment: you wait four months and then two comments all at once.  I'm interested in this too, will post back any findings.  Guessing we'd need a new helper wrapping around html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteSubstitution

Comment: @robert once i added authentication to my pages that just opened up a can of worms and i ended up mostly turning off caching throughout my site. had to prioritize other things. i'll wait for a better official response

Answer (score 3):

"Donut Caching" means using Response.WriteSubstitution method. If you look at MVC source you will see that System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial method is using Response.Output (HtmlHelper.cs, line 277 - last line in 'RenderPartialInternal' method) - so you need create your own html helpers for handling more complex situations.